# Configuring Samba on Linux so that the network share does not need a login / password

Tags: linux, networking, nas, samba, raspberry-pi

I'm eager to use a Raspberry Pi as a low-load NAS, and I was reading the guide at:
http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/

In the tutorial they configure the samba.conf by adding:

`security = user`

However I want my network share to be easily accessible, so that when (in Windows 7) you click on Network and the PC as appears in this image (not mine):

[image]

Say you click on the computer 'PAPA', it directly opens up the files instead of asking for a username and password.

My guess is to add a `#` before `security = user`, to comment it out.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

There was a `security = share` to make the whole share read only or read / write to everyone in older versions of Samba but it doesn't exist anymore.

You want to look at `guest only` and `guest user` configuration parameters to remap unknown users (no password typed) to a configured guest account.

Machines that are in a domain will always pop up the username / password screen but you can type whatever and you'll connect using the guest account.

Here is a minimal smb.conf that would do what you want :

```
[global]

   netbios name = server
   workgroup = HOME

   security = user
   map to guest = bad user
   guest ok = yes
   guest only = yes
   guest account = sacha
   force user = sacha
   force group = sacha

[public]

   browseable = yes
   read only = no
   path = /srv/samba/public
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any need to change the `security = user` option.

```
[PAPA]
   comment = Whatever
   path = /your/path
   read only = no
   public = yes
   create mask = 0666
   force create mode = 0666
   directory mask = 2777
   force directory mode = 2777
```

And then you simple need to set permissions on /your/path so that `other` has the needed permissions, e.g. `2777`